# Way to render a new component onClick in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to render a new component onclick a button in react js. Am using functional components and I can't handle it. Eg:  am in the UserManagement component and on a button click I need to render another component named employee management.

Comment: can you share code ? I think conditional rendering is solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can `conditionally` render your component.

Example :

**EmployeeManagement.js**

```
const EmployeeManagement = () => {
   ....

   return (
    <div>
      EmployeeManagement
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UserManagement.js**

```
const UserManagement = () => {
   const [hasRender, setRender] = useState(false);
   const onShow = React.useCallback(() => setRender(true), []);


   return (
     <>
      <button onClick={onShow}>Show Employee Management</button>
      {hasRender && <EmployeeManagement />}
    </>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a visible state & toggle it in onClick:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

onClick = () => {setVisible(true)}
```

then render it like this:

```
{visible && <EmployeeManagement onClick={onClick} />}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to add a local state in `UserManagement`,
that holds a `boolean` value indication whether the component should be hidden or shown.

Then you will have something like:

```js
function UserManagement() {
   const [compIsShown, setCompIsShown] = useState(false);

   return (
      // Whatever else you're rendering.
      <button onClick={() => setCompIsShown(true)}>...</button>
      {compIsShown && <OtherComp />}
   )
}
```

What will happen is that `compIsShown` will initialize as false,
so this condition `compIsShown && <OtherComp />` will prevent it from rendering.
Then, when you click the button, the state will set, causing a re-render, except now the condition will be true, so `<OtherComp>` will be rendered.

There are other ways to go about this.
Depends mostly on the use-case.