# Render a whole new componnent on callback event (onClick for example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a whole new component into a page when there's is event.
For example I have a button that sends request to DB, and I want that whenever this button is clicked a NEW toaster will open that will say "sent".

I saw this - [Way to render a new component onClick in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476529/way-to-render-a-new-component-onclick-in-react-js)

And it just shows how to set toggle to show or hide element, but I want to add new one, so I will be able to add multiple of them.

```js
export default function Demo() {
  function handleClick() {
    // show notification "clicked"
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click to update</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working sample in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-perlman-f23rcw). I have used `ant design` to generate the notification. This comes out of the box without custom config. You can click the button as many times as you want and each time a new notification will be displayed.

The only things you need to do is:

- Add `antd` to your dependencies in `package.json`
- Add `import "antd/dist/antd.css"` to your index file
- Start using `notification` right away in your component.

Comment: @eliezra236 does this answer your question?